# How do I find Vo in the circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, laplace-transform

I1 + I2 = I3

I1 = Vi/Z1 ... Z1 = (1+sCR1)/sC

I1= Vi(sC)/(1+sCR1)

I2= Vi/R1

I3= -Vo/R1

I1 + I2 = I3

Vi[(sc)/(1+sCR1) + (1/R1)] =-Vo/R1

-Vi[(R1sC)/(1+sCR1) + 1] = Vo

How do I change back to time domain?

[image]

Comment: Why are there 2 R1?

Comment: If you want to see how Vo looks in the time domain you first have to specify Vi in the time domain.

Answer (score 1):

The opamp is inverting.
The DC gain is R2/R1.
The AC gain is higher at higher frequencies since C couples its series R1 to be parallel with the other R1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just concerned that you can't find the inverse transform of your transfer function in a table, it's because it's disguised. You can separate your expression into two expressions, one with the form 1/(s+a) and the other of the form s/(s+a). The former expression is in all tables, but the second is not. It's an sF(s) which has an inverse transform that's the derivative of the first.

If you work through the algebra, you'll have the impulse response of your circuit. It won't have any practical use. There aren't any sources of impulses and if there were there wouldn't be an op amp with the bandwidth needed. There's no time domain expression for the circuit that will be useable for a variety of inputs. Think of the difference between the responses to an impulse and a step. The impulse response is an amplified negative impulse preceding a jump to a positive value declining exponentially to zero. The response to a step is a jump to a negative value declining exponentially to half that value. What would be a time domain expression that could cover both cases?

BTW, R2 got lost along the way in your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEjuZJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}-\text{V}_-}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

When working with an ideal opamp we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\tag4$$

In this case we notice that \$\text{V}_+=0\space\text{V}\$, so we can rewrite \$(3)\$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

And solve for \$\text{V}_\text{o}\$:

$$\text{V}_\text{o}=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\text{R}_2}\tag6$$

Applying this to your circuit we see that:

$$\text{R}_2=\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\tag7$$

So, we get:

$$\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}\tag8$$

Now, using the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write the output voltage:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{V}_\text{o}\left(t\right)&=-\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}+\text{R}_1\right)\delta\left(t-\tau\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\tau-t}{\text{CR}}\right)\right)\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\cdot\left(\frac{\displaystyle\left(\text{R}+\text{R}_1\right)\left(2\theta\left(t\right)-1\right)\text{V}_\text{i}\left(t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}}-\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}^2}\cdot\int\limits_0^t\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\exp\left(\frac{\tau-t}{\text{CR}}\right)\space\text{d}\tau\right)
\end{split}\tag9
\end{equation}